# Symbols for options on gold futures

Tags: options, cme

I have a historical data set containing only options on gold futures. If I print out a unique list of option symbols I get:

`GC, L01, L02, L03, L04, L05, L06, L07, L08, L09, L10, L11, L12, L13, L14, L15, L16, L17, L18, L19, L20, L21, L22, L23, L24, L25, L26, L27, L28, L29, L30, L31, OG1, OG2, OG3, OG4, OG5.`

On the CME contract spec they only list two option types, [American Options](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold_contractSpecs_options.html?optionProductId=7488#optionProductId=192) with symbol GC, and [weekly options](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold_contractSpecs_options.html?optionProductId=7488#optionProductId=7488) with symbols OG1 thru OG5.
My question is what are the other symbols L01 thru L31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/lookups/advisories/clearing/Chadv14-394.html?source=rss

looks like they are short term gold options that were delisted...

Comment: May I ask how you found this?

Comment: google, simple as...